# Why is the Item Position messed up after override?

Tags: javascript, position, adobe-indesign, extendscript

**The Situation:**

My Script creates a weekplanner with the masterpage as template.

What's happening in the script is:

- Create Page
- Apply Masterpage
- Override each item
- Change content of each item
- do this for the whole dates-array length

**The Problem:**

The position of the masterPageItems after overriding gets messed up. 
I've made two screenshots as demonstration.

**Now the real weirdness about this is, that it gets messed up on a "custom-size" document, but it doesn't get messed up on A4-Format...**

I've already tried to restore the geometricBounds of each item after overriding it, but this doesnt seem to work either...

Do you have any idea what could be causing this behaviour?

**The masterpage:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0PAh.png

**Messed up after overriding:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AWvh.png

---

**EDIT:**
As proof that restoring the geometricBounds doesn't work, I did the following:

```
function OverrideMasterItems(currPage) {  
  var allItems = currPage.masterPageItems;  
  var itemPos;
  for(var i=0;i<allItems.length;i++){  
    try{
        itemPos = allItems[i].geometricBounds;
        allItems[i].override(currPage);
        allItems[i].geometricBounds = itemPos;
        $.writeln("Original itemPos: " + itemPos);
        $.writeln("New itemPos: " + allItems[i].geometricBounds);
        if(itemPos == allItems[i].geometricBounds) {
            $.writeln("same position");
        }
    }  
    catch(e){}  
  }  
}
```

As you see I assign the items original geometric bounds again and in the console it says that it's the same value - but it looks like in the screenshots. Also it doesn't write "same position" - which means the if-statement isn't true...

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it! For future reference:**

It wasn't a programming bug, but some awkward InDesign "Bug(?!)" that lead to this weird behaviour:

I copied the elements of the Masterpage from a different document, that had different dimensions, and I just resized the textfields to fit the new format.

That's what caused the behaviour - it seems like the textfields still have some information from the other document I got it from and that this information wasn't removable/editable.

Because even deleting the paragraph styles etc. didn't change the weird behaviour...

As I'm pretty new to InDesign scripting I don't know if this a common thing you guys know about, but this gave me headaches... ;)

**EDIT 1: I didn't solve it! Still not working sometimes!**

Okay, it's still happening, and I just don't understand why... As the script executes the "override" on an item, the item gets repositioned to a completely wrong position...